# Cuda 6.5 complains about missing libraries in Fedora 20

Tags: cuda, fedora, fedora20

When I tried to run a CUDA example (from /usr/local/cuda/samples/) many errors appeared from missing libraries, including libGLU.so, libX11.so, libXi.so and many others. There where installed, but re installing didn't have any effect. Of course compilation couldn't continue.

Some libraries where shown as optional during CUDA installation (by manual installation after finished CUDA installation) and I did not care about them. I didn't keep any log so I lost that information.

I searched for missing symbolic links and also wrong versions of the libraries, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research I found that the libraries are in their devel packages. So I had to install the following (with yum):

- libXi-devel
- mesa-libGLU-devel
- libXmu-devel
- libX11-devel
- freeglut-devel

Now, this brought a new problem with libGLU at compilation time because of the installation of mesa-libGLU-devel (I was trying with the examples) because the reference to libGL.so is no longer there, so I had to reinstall the NVIDIA drivers, which corrected the broken link.

After that the compilation of examples worked. I found the second part of the solution [here](http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/docdisplay?lndocid=migr-5094265)

Comment: The need to install these libraries separately is already documented in the [getting started guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html#runfile-libraries).

Comment: And that's why everyone should read instructions. Should I delete the question?

Comment: Although the installation given by the guide is what I missed at first, the second problem did happened and I found how to fix it, maybe other people will look here first, and I added the source so if anyone wants further reading there is the source.